# How do I alter a T-SQL FUNCTION with a dependent default constraint?

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions

I run the T-SQL script below (ALTER) and get:

```
Cannot ALTER 'dbo.MyFunction' because it is being referenced by object 'DF_MyTable_SomeValue'
```

For example, from a statement like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction] ()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
```

Is there an easy way to alter a FUNCTION with dependent table DEFAULT constraints?

Comment: Easy? Yes. Convenient? Not so much. Script constraint. Drop constraint. Alter function. Reapply constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no easy way to do that

You really need to drop the default constraints referencing the UDF before altering it. (Or just alter the constraint removing the UDF reference while you update it).

This happens because the engine is afraid you mess things up due to you changing a default constraint on the fly (that thing is supposed to compute values at inserts and inserts can be happening while you update it).